# How to run a gradle web application?

Tags: gradle, spring-tool-suite

I have converted a maven project to gradle  , I am using Spring tool suite and all the dependency jars are uploaded successfully .When I build the project it builds successfully.
but I am not getting an idea how to run this web application , I tried to make a war so that I can used tomcat to deploy , I found tomcat plugin for that but when I insert tomcat plugin in my build.gradle file ,it gives me error:
**Plugin with tomcat id not found**

Please help someone I am just stuck , I am assuming the structure it follows is same as gradle and as I am using jsp pages and xml files can I keep these files in my resources folder .

**How can i create the war file of project and deploy using eclipse-wtp in tomcat?**

Answer (score 14):

To create a war just use: `apply plugin: 'war'`

For WTP add these lines to your build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
```

To deploy the war file with tomcat within your build you can use the [cargo plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin). In that way you can start after the deployment e.g. integration tests etc.

To deploy the war file within eclipse tomcat: You must first run `gradle eclipse` after you put the above `apply plugin: ...` into your build.gradle. Then refresh within eclipse and add the web project to your tomcat.

Comment: where this war file gets stored ?i followed these steps, added eclipse and eclipse-wtp and war plugin but not able to see where the war file is created after successfully build...

Comment: look at <your_eclipse_project>/build/libs directory